# Embedding PDFont after adjusting character widths

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, pdfbox

I want to create a PDF file conforming to the PDF/A standard by using Apache PDFBox. To conform to PDF/A, all used fonts have to be embedded. I can use either the standard fonts or load one from a file, but I need to adjust the character width of several glyphs. I can do this by loading a font (or using a standard font) and modify it afterwards, as shown below.

```
doc = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = new PDPage();
doc.addPage( page );
InputStream fontStream = PDFCreator.class.getResourceAsStream("ArialMT.ttf");
PDFont font = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(doc, fontStream);
List<Float> test = font.getWidths();
test.set(101-32, 2000f);
font.setWidths(test);
```

But how can I embed the modified font?

Comment: Why do you need to change the character width of glyphs in a font? Is it to manipulate the spacing between characters in the PDF? I'm really interested to know because just thinking about it gives me shivers...

Comment: Yes, I want to adjust the spacing between characters, matching it to different (unavailable) fonts with varying character widths. But I think it might be possible (and better) using appendRawCommands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Embedding the original font with a patched **Widths** font dictionary entry

If you *use* your manipulated font, it will be embedded. If you e.g. continue your code like this:

```
PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
stream.setFont(font, 12);
stream.beginText();
stream.moveTextPositionByAmount(30, 600);
stream.drawString("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
stream.moveTextPositionByAmount(0, -20);
stream.drawString("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
stream.moveTextPositionByAmount(0, -20);
stream.drawString("0123456789");
stream.endText();
stream.close();

doc.save("embedFont.pdf");
```

you get a PDF like this using PDFBox 1.8.8:

[image: "embedFont.pdf" screenshot]

As you see, your manipulation of the width of 'e'

```
test.set(101-32, 2000f);
```

makes the space for that letter fairly broad.

If you look into the PDF, you will find this **Widths** array in the font dictionary:

```
/Widths [278.0 278.0 355.0 556.0 556.0 889.0 667.0 191.0 333.0 333.0
389.0 584.0 278.0 333.0 278.0 278.0 556.0 556.0 556.0 556.0
556.0 556.0 556.0 556.0 556.0 556.0 278.0 278.0 584.0 584.0
584.0 556.0 1015.0 667.0 667.0 722.0 722.0 667.0 611.0 778.0
722.0 278.0 500.0 667.0 556.0 833.0 722.0 778.0 667.0 778.0
722.0 667.0 611.0 722.0 667.0 944.0 667.0 667.0 611.0 278.0
278.0 278.0 469.0 556.0 333.0 556.0 556.0 500.0 556.0 2000.0 
...
```

Your `2000` is there alright. As far as the PDF is concerned, your change has been stored.

Admittedly, though, the width of 'e' in the embedded font program is not changed. If you want to change that, you should pre-process the font file with the widths adjusted:

### Embedding a patched font

You can use e.g. Google's [sfntly](https://code.google.com/p/sfntly/) to patch the font on the fly. In that case the analog code could look like this:

```
byte[] fontBytes = null;
try (   InputStream arialMtResource = getClass().getResourceAsStream("ArialMT.ttf");
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()   )
{
    patchAdvanceWidth(arialMtResource, baos, 101-29, 2000);
    fontBytes = baos.toByteArray();
}

try (   ByteArrayInputStream fontStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fontBytes);   )
{
    PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    doc.addPage(page);
    PDFont font = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(doc, fontStream);
    PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
    stream.setFont(font, 12);
    stream.beginText();
    stream.moveTextPositionByAmount(30, 600);
    stream.drawString("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
    stream.moveTextPositionByAmount(0, -20);
    stream.drawString("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    stream.moveTextPositionByAmount(0, -20);
    stream.drawString("0123456789");
    stream.endText();
    stream.close();

    doc.save("target/test-outputs/embedPatchedFont.pdf");
}
```

making use of this helper method:

```
void patchAdvanceWidth(InputStream is, OutputStream os, int entry, int newValue) throws IOException
{
    FontFactory fontFactory = FontFactory.getInstance();
    Builder[] builders = fontFactory.loadFontsForBuilding(is);
    Builder builder = builders[0];

    HorizontalMetricsTable.Builder hmtxBuilder = (HorizontalMetricsTable.Builder) builder.getTableBuilder(Tag.hmtx);
    WritableFontData hmtxData = hmtxBuilder.data();

    int offset = 0 + (entry * 4) + 0;
    hmtxData.writeUShort(offset, newValue);
    hmtxBuilder.setData(hmtxData);

    Font font = builder.build();
    fontFactory.serializeFont(font, os);
}
```

Comment: Yes, the 2000 can be found, but it's not PDF/A conform anymore, as the width doesn't match the embedded one. So I would need to somehow change the font file and load the new file? Is there no way to directly embed a PDFont (or creating an inputStream from the PDFont to embed)?

Comment: I wasn't aware from your question that that discrepancy of the widths (in the font dictionary and the font program itself) was the issue, I thought it was about the embedding. That been said, there are libraries for on-the-fly font manipulation. I'd try and use such a library.

Comment: @whitespaceranger *the width doesn't match the embedded one* - would the alternative approach I added to the answer help?

Comment: Thank you, your added approach was indeed what I was looking for. It makes it possible to create a new font matching the unavailabe one in several aspects, which was my intention. But after reading the comment on my question, I think it would be enough to 'fake' the font by adjusting the character spacing and using fontsize for the height. So I'll take a look at the 'appendRawCommands' method, if I can use it for my adjustments, as it should be a better solution than creating new fonts.

Comment: Usually you indeed should adjust widths in the content stream, especially for kerning or similar purposes. But if you statically want to adjust character widths for all uses of the font in question in the document, font manipulation is a valid alternative approach.